# Optimización de código en una función. Python

Tags: python

He creado la siguiente función:

```
def partidos_por_equipos(partidos, equipos):

    result = []
    for i in partidos:
        for fecha, local, goles_local, visitante, goles_visitante in i:
            if local in equipos or visitante in equipos:
                result.append((fecha, local, goles_local, visitante, goles_visitante))
    return result
```

He tenido que utilizar dos bucles `for` porque "partidos" es una lista que a su vez contiene varias sublistas y estas contienen tuplas. Ej:

```
partidos = [[(datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'FC Barcelona', 2, 'Málaga CF', 1), 
(datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'RC Deportivo', 2, 'Athletic Club', 0)]]
```

La duda es si existe alguna función para que "partidos" se quede como una sola lista de tuplas o que acceda directamente a las tuplas sin tener que acceder a cada sublista. Y si no hay forma, saber si se puede ahorrar líneas de código en la función que he creado. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si `partidos` es una lista con un solo elemento (que es otra lista con las tuplas), como es el caso en tu ejemplo, basta que lo extraigas, así:

```
partidos = partidos[0]
```

En el caso más general en que pueda tener dentro varias listas, cada una con tuplas, lo que quieres es "aplanar" la estructura, es decir, deshacerte de las listas internas. Esto puedes hacerlo así:

```
aplanado = []
for lista in partidos:
   aplanado.extend(lista)
```

y así `aplanado` sería una lista cuyos elementos ya son los partidos.

### Simplificar la función

Sin aplanar la lista, la función puede reducirse a una línea si haces uso de las *list comprehensions*, pero aún así sigue habiendo bucles internos, sólo que dentro de la *comprehension*. Así:

```
def partidos_por_equipos(partidos, equipos):
    return [partido for x in partidos for partido in x 
            if partido[1] in equipos or partido[3] in equipos]
```

También se puede hacer un uso creativo de los conjuntos. Si conviertes cada partido en un conjunto, puedes hacer la intersección con el conjunto de equipos y si esa intersección no es vacía, te quedas con el partido. Con este enfoque:

```
def partidos_por_equipos(partidos, equipos):
    return [partido for x in partidos for partido in x 
            if set(partido) & set(equipos)]
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento (considero que hay más de una lista dentro de la principal):

```
import datetime
partidos = [[(datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'FC Barcelona', 2, 'Málaga CF', 1), 
             (datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'RC Deportivo', 2, 'Athletic Club', 0)],
            [(datetime.date(2000, 9, 10), 'RC Deportivo', 2, 'Alavés', 0)]
           ]
print(partidos_por_equipos(partidos, 
                           ["Ciudad Real", "Alavés", "RC Deportivo"]))
```

```
[(datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'RC Deportivo', 2, 'Athletic Club', 0),
 (datetime.date(2000, 9, 10), 'RC Deportivo', 2, 'Alavés', 0)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Si lo manejas como una lista, donde cada elemento es un diccionario, se vuelve mucho más claro de leer y simple de recorrer.

```
    partidos = [{"fecha":datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), "equipo1":"FC Barcelona", "marcador1":2, "equipo2":"Málaga CF", "marcador2":2}, 
{"fecha":datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), "equipo1":"RC Deportivo", "marcador1":2, "equipo2":"Athletic Club", "marcador2":0}]
```

Comment: puedes explicar tu codigo , estas respuestas son consideradas como baja calidad

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, el problema es que partidos es la concatenación o unión de dos listas. Es por eso que partidos contiene a su vez otras listas.

Comment: Lo que intenté decir es que, teniendo en cuenta que lo que se pedía era optimizar, en lugar de manejar los datos con una lista de listas, y controlar el acceso a los datos por posición, es mejor utilizar una lista con diccionarios que son autoexplicativos. Y sólo necesita recorrer una lista, y llamar cada dato por su nombre.